# Open several .SVG with Inkview as a slide show?

Tags: windows, inkscape, svg

Despite Inkscape's [InkView](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkview) being intended to be used in a "slide show" mode with full screen mode and navigation keys,  I can't find how to make this work on Windows.

I can open single .SVG by right-clicking: `open with ... InkView`
but I can't do the same with *multiple* .SVG selected.

I have tried to create a .BAT file with the files listed, such as:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkview.exe S:\myFolderA\file01.svg S:\myFolderB\office\file02.svg S:\myFolderB\file03.svg"
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked with quotations marks around Program Files (x86)

```
START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Inkscape\inkview.exe S:\myFolderA\file01.svg ...
```